# concat array after filter javascript

Tags: javascript

this code doesn't work

```
 var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
 var arrayJoin=[];
arrayJoin.concat(arr1.filter(function (val) {
                    return val == "a";
    }));

console.log(arrayJoin);
```

this works fine

```
arrayJoin=arr1.filter(function (val) {
                    return val == "a";
    }));
```

any idea how to concat the filter array?

Comment: [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) `[...]The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does **not** change the existing arrays, but instead  **returns a new** array.[...]`

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new Array, so what do you need `concat` for

Comment: this is one concat in a series

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
arrayJoin = arrayJoin.concat(arr1.filter(function (val) {
                    return val == "a";
    }));
```